# Change text color of Material TextView on surface and on background through theming

Tags: android, android-studio, material-design, android-theme, material-components-android

I'm following Material Design's [guidelines](https://material.io/develop/android/theming/color/) on how to do color theming. We can alter some attributes that are already defined to customize the color and/or shape of a certain component. Some useful attributes that are pertinent to color theming include: `colorSurface` (e.g. changes the fill color of the `Material Card` component), `colorSecondary` (e.g. changes the fill color of a FAB) and `colorOnSecondary` (e.g. changes the fill color of the FAB icon).

Currently, I have two resource directories: `values` and `values-night` for light-themed and dark-themed UI respectively. They control the value of the colors that are assigned to the color attributes. Codes:

```
<!-- Light-themed UI color values -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#546e7a</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryVariant">#29434e</color>
    <color name="colorOnPrimary">#ffffff</color>
    <color name="colorSecondary">#d81b60</color>
    <color name="colorSecondaryVariant">#a00037</color>
    <color name="colorOnSecondary">#000000</color>
    <color name="colorSurface">#ffffff</color>
</resources>

<!-- Dark-themed UI color values -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#546e7a</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryVariant">#29434e</color>
    <color name="colorOnPrimary">#ffffff</color>
    <color name="colorSecondary">#d81b60</color>
    <color name="colorSecondaryVariant">#a00037</color>
    <color name="colorOnSecondary">#000000</color>
    <color name="colorSurface">#000000</color>
</resources>

<!-- Style resource file that changes in accordance to current default night mode -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
    <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/colorOnPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorSecondary">@color/colorSecondary</item>
    <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/colorOnSecondary</item>
    <item name="colorSurface">@color/colorSurface</item>
    <item name="colorOnSurface">@color/colorOnSurface</item>
</style>
```

Text on some components (e.g. buttons) is affected by `colorOnPrimary`. When the components uses both `colorPrimary` and `colorOnPrimary`, I can control the colors used well. However, components' color like `Material TextView`'s color does not depend on `colorOnSurface` and instead can be modified through [special attributes](https://material.io/develop/android/theming/typography/) like `textAppearanceHeadline1`. Of course, I can simply modify `android:textColor` on `textAppearanceHeadline1` to follow the color of `colorOnSurface`. However, `Material TextView` does sometimes appear on background (not surfaces) and when this happens, I want the `android:textColor` to have the value `colorOnBackground` instead.

I can probably just apply the style with `colorOnSurface` to all `Material TextView` and only override the style with `colorOnBackground` when a `Material TextView` does appear on the background. However, is there any way that I can change the value used by `android:textColor` automatically depending on where the text appears?

Comment: Have you tried using platform attributes such as **android: textColorPrimary**?